Python backtrader buy and sell not working
I want to make a simple trading bot for fun and test it using backtrader. My data is correct and everything works fine however on the graph there is no sign of buying or selling shares.
This is how the graph looks:

My code:
import backtrader as bt


import backtrader as bt


def calcTrade(oldPrice: float, price: float) -> int:
    if oldPrice < price:
        return 1
    if oldPrice > price:
        return 2
    return 0


class Strategy(bt.Strategy):
    params = (
        ('ma_period', 20),
    )

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def next(self):
        last_price = self.data.close[-2]
        current_price = self.data.close[-1]
        action = calcTrade(last_price, current_price)
        
        if action == 1:
            self.buy(data=self.data, size=1)
            print('b', current_price)
        elif action == 2:
            self.sell(data=self.data, size=1)
            print('s', current_price)


cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.addstrategy(Strategy)

data = bt.feeds.YahooFinanceData(dataname='data/^GSPC.csv')
cerebro.adddata(data)

cerebro.broker.setcash(1000000)
cerebro.broker.setcommission(0.0)

cerebro.run()
cerebro.plot(style='candle')

This is the csv data:
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adjusted Close
2023-12-29,4782.88,4788.43,4751.99,4769.83,4769.83
2023-12-28,4786.44,4793.3,4780.98,4783.35,4783.35
...

I added printing when the self.buy() and self.sell() functions are called and get a lot of messages printed but still nothing on the graph.
This is how the console output looks:
s 3919.25
s 3892.09
b 3895.08
s 3808.1
b 3852.97


Isn't there a sign of selling, by red lines?

Oh you are right @mkrieger1 I didn't see that sorry. But what about buying and why don't the cash and value graphs move?
